# Could it calculate from MEID to IMEI

Tags: smartphone, imei

I have a MEID number of smartphone, I need to get IMEI numbers corresponding MEID using any formula or algorithms. 
Is it possible? If it is possible, Please let me know about right way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  An MEID number identifies a CDMA device while IMEI numbers are used to identify GSM devices.  Both are unique to a single device so there is no such thing as a "corresponding IMEI number".

However, some smartphones have radios that support both CDMA and GSM (an Apple iPhone 5 from Sprint/Verizon for example).  Such devices will have both an MEID number and an IMEI number.